# quantiles dependent on additional variables

Tags: r

Here my sample dataframe (in R):
Let's say I have the age and height of these people.

```
age <-c(3.1,3.2,3.1,3.2,3.4,
        4.1,4.4,4.5,4.6,4.1,
        5.2,5.1,5.1,5.8,5.9,
        6.3,6.1,6.2,6.2,6.6)

height <- c(1.1, 1.2, 1.0, 1.5, 1.2, 
       1.3, 1.3, 1.6, 1.2, 1.4,
       1.4, 1.2, 1.7, 1.6, 1.5,
       1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.6, 1.7)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(age,height))
```

Now I calculate quantiles.

```
df$percentile <- with(df, cut(height, breaks = quantile(height, 
probs=    seq(0,1, by=0.25)),include.lowest=TRUE, 
                   labels=c("p25","p50","p75","p100")))
```

Now, I have the problem that height is influenced by age. 
Can I divide my sample into height-quantiles based on age? For example someone with 6 years that is 1.5 will be on the upper percentile, even though this person would rather short in light of the age (see plot).

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you want a quantile regression. See the `quantreg` package, it has an excellent vignette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with the data.table package? It is a package that makes data.frames easier to work with. Unfortunately, I don't know how to answer your question without using it.  Keeping that in mind, I think this is what you are looking for.

```
require(data.table)
df<-data.table(age=runif(100,min=3,max=7))
df[,height:=rnorm(100, mean=.5+age/6, sd=age*.020)]
for(i in 3:6){
  my.breaks=quantile(df[age>=i & age <i+1,]$height)
  df[age>=i & age <i+1, new.percentile:=cut(height,breaks=my.breaks, include.lowest = TRUE, 
                                            labels=c("p25","p50","p75","p100"))]
}
```

On the first line, we load the data.table package. Then we create a new toy dataset because yours was too small to get quantiles to work with the individual ages. So this data.table has 100 observations where the age comes from a uniform distribution from 3 to 7. Then we add a height column, where the height comes from the normal distribution where the mean and standard deviation are functions of the age. The parameters were just arbitrarily chosen to get something that looked reasonable.

Next we make a for loop where we find our percentile breaks by only looking at one year ranges in the age column. Then we apply your code to label the height percentile only on the data that falls in that age range.

Here is some of the data.table after the for loop. Is this what you were looking for?

```
        age   height        new.percentile
    1: 3.826293 1.049781            p50
    2: 3.903765 1.116287            p75
    3: 3.931612 1.075756            p75
    4: 3.940625 1.165758           p100
    5: 4.191432 1.142972            p25
    6: 4.211323 1.193299            p25
    7: 4.298498 1.192850            p25
    8: 4.794392 1.161370            p25
    9: 4.839184 1.190125            p25
   10: 5.086999 1.195572            p25
```

Comment: Thank you for this snipped and the explanation. That is it.